# Copy Cell value and paste into another excel particular worksheet and particular cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to copy the data one excel to another excel 
My question:
In the one workbook Sheet1 column C & D contains some data that data i need to copy another excel that's in closed condition presently. I need to copy Range("C" , i) and Range("D" , i) in to another excel sheet3 B2 and C2 accordingly. in that mainthing each rows copy paste into different workbooks i given a path in **H** Columns

```
 Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
  Dim Openfile As String
  Dim lstrow As Long
  Dim i As Long
  lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 2 To lstrow

 'Copy the data
 Sheets("Main").Range("C:D", i).Copy
 'Activate the destination worksheet
  Workbook.Openfile = Range("H", i)
  Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
  'Select the target range
   Range("B2:C2").Select
   'Paste in the target destination
     ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Next
    End Sub
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBchx.png)

Comment: `Range("C" & i & ":D" & i)`. Then, it might be helpful to read the [`Workbooks.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) method documentation to fix the multiple issues in `workbook.openfile...`.

Comment: @BigBen runtime error 1004 in      Workbooks.Openfile = Range("H", i) in this line

Comment: @BigBen and can u possible to look into this also this is also error 1004 https://superuser.com/questions/1408434/rename-the-files-based-on-cell-value